# Python string.format replace index

Tags: python, string, format

I have the following matrix and I am trying to replace item {6} or any other.

```
cells = str(input("cache cache: "))

matrix = """
---------
| {0} {1} {2} |
| {3} {4} {5} |
| {6} {7} {8} |
---------
""".format(*cells)
print(matrix)

coordinates = [
                ("1", "3"), ("2", "3"), ("3", "3"),
                ("1", "2"), ("2", "2"), ("3", "2"),
                ("1", "1"), ("2", "1"), ("3", "1")
]


given_coordinates = input("Enter the coordinates: ").split(", ")
t_given_coordinates = tuple(given_coordinates)


for x in coordinates:
    if x == t_given_coordinates:
        print(matrix.format(*cells.replace(matrix[6], "X")))
```

The user is supposed to enter the coordinates that relate to the matrix, for example:
The given matrix is given in the first input: X_X_O____
From here, if the user inputs coordinates (1, 1), item {6} from matrix gets replaced by 1 X.
I don't know how to proceed further, I'm relatively new to Python and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should do with this:

- Create a function that prints the current playing field, given the cells. So, you can print it whenever you want.
- Change the item of the cells list, which corresponds to the entered coordinates.

In the example below I used your code to look up the index of the cell you need to change by adding `cellnum = coordinates.index(t_given_coordinates)`. This line defines a new integer variable that holds the cell number according to your map. You may then use this index to change the content of this cell and redraw the complete thing.

```
cells = ['-']*9

def print_matrix(cells):
    matrix = """
    ---------
    | {0} {1} {2} |
    | {3} {4} {5} |
    | {6} {7} {8} |
    ---------
    """.format(*cells)
    print(matrix)

coordinates = [
                ("1", "3"), ("2", "3"), ("3", "3"),
                ("1", "2"), ("2", "2"), ("3", "2"),
                ("1", "1"), ("2", "1"), ("3", "1")
]


print_matrix(cells)

end = False
while not end:
    try:
        given_coordinates = input("Enter the coordinates: ").split(", ")
        t_given_coordinates = tuple(given_coordinates)
        cellnum = coordinates.index(t_given_coordinates)
        cells[cellnum] = "X"
        print_matrix(cells)
    except:
        print("That was an invalid input")
        end = True
```

The output will look somewhat like that:

```
    ---------
    | - - - |
    | - - - |
    | - - - |
    ---------
    
Enter the coordinates: 1, 1

    ---------
    | - - - |
    | - - - |
    | X - - |
    ---------
    
Enter the coordinates: 2, 3

    ---------
    | - X - |
    | - - - |
    | X - - |
    ---------
    
Enter the coordinates: hello world
That was an invalid input
```

But, if I may suggest a slight change:

- The initial filling of the cells could already be the cell indices. So, the user just has to enter the index of the next cell to fill, which is a single integer. That's much less prone to raise errors. So, when the field is empty, it just reads:

```
---------
| 0 1 2 |
| 3 4 5 |
| 6 7 8 |
---------
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I would represent your choises as simple flat list and calculate the position inside this list from the tuples you get as inputs like so:

```
def print_list(l):
    """Takes a list of 9 elements and prints them in a 3x3 matrix
    replacing None with empty spaces."""
    matrix = """
---------
| {0} {1} {2} |
| {3} {4} {5} |
| {6} {7} {8} |
---------
"""

    print(matrix.format(*(what or " " for what in l)))


# use a list to store the taken fields
choices = ["X", None, None,
           "X", "O", "O",
            None, None, None]

print_list(choices)


c = ("3","1")  # the tuple your input gave you
# create numbers from it
c = list(map(int,c))
# calculate list position
pos = (c[0]-1)*3+c[1]-1
# fill correct letter in
choices [pos] = "X"

print_list(choices)
```

to get

```
---------
| X     |
| X O O |
|       |
--------- 

---------
| X     |
| X O O |
| X     |
---------
```

Obviously you would need to

- check if the position in the list is still `None` to avoid overwriting X by O (or reverse)
- change the letter to be written to X or O (whoever ones turn it is)
- determine if a winning move was made
- ...

See f.e. [Search in duckduckgo.com for `python + tic tac to on stackoverflow.com`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+tic+tac+toe+site%3Astackoverflow.com&atb=v168-1&ia=web&iai=r1-3&page=1&adx=sltb&sexp=%7B%22v7exp%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22sltexp%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22wiadrk%22%3A%22b%22%7D)